# incompatible pointer types assigning to 'nsmutablearray ' from 'nsarray ' in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

```
users = [users arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arrayvalue];
```

users is a `NSMutableArray` and arrayvalue is also a `NSMutableArray`, I am adding value of arrayvalue to the users array but I am getting a warning "incompatible pointer types assigning to `NSMutableArray` from `NSArray` ".

I hav searched, but was unable to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 9):

Although `arrayvalue` is NSMutableArray, the return value of `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` is `NSArray`, and that's why you get this warning.

You should call `[users addObjectsFromArray:arrayvalue];` which  alters the array <strike>returns`NSMutableArray`</strike>.

See the [`NSMutableArray` reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.